# Web app instancing performance hit with dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a asp.net mvc app where a lot of things are dependent on knowing the url of the web request (it's multi-tenant). Currently the HttpContext is being injected in a lot of constructors (through a wrapper that sets up some variables based on the context) using Simple Injector. This means that most things have to be instanced "per web request" vs per application.

Now what I could do here is just pass the HttpContext wrapper, or only the required data, in methods rather that constructor injection.

What I would like some clue on is the actual performance difference. Because it does make it a lot less elegant having to always pass the wrapper/data. This is however a quite high-traffic site so I will definitely consider changing it up.

I do realize this depends a bit on what's going on in the constructor, but assume that all it does is assign dependencies.

To clarify I do not have a specific performance problem. This is only optimization and I'm wondering if it's worth going through the work of refactoring to achieve this.

Comment: Does you `HttpContext`-wrapper contain data, or logic to retrieve the data whenever a property or method is called? If the latter, then there is no need to be instanced per web request; you can use a single instance (since it will use the HttpContext.Current behind the scene).

Comment: So what you are saying is that you are [injecting runtime data into your components](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: I'm missing numbers and facts here. Is this hypothetical or do you have a performance problem? Have you measured it? Have you profiled it to find out where the problem is? I am tempte to close this question without such information.

Comment: @Steven I added a paragraph clarifying that is about optimization.

Comment: @Maarten The wrapper sets up a bunch of stuff based on HttpContext so I won't be able to have a single instance of the wrapper.

Comment: @Steven Regarding injecting runtime, I think that my scenario is more akin to the example at the bottom where the runtime data is abstracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just a wrapper you can place a provider in between, which you could be singleton, which makes it possible for all consumers to be singleton as well.

Like this:

```
public interface IHttpContextProvider
{
    HttpContext CurrentContext { get; }
}

public class HttpContextProvider : IHttpContextProvider
{
    public HttpContext CurrentContext => HttpContext.Current;
}

public interface IMyContextWrapper
{
    string CurrentRoute { get; }
}

public class MyContextWrapper : IMyContextWrapper
{
    private readonly IHttpContextProvider httpContextProvider;

    public MyContextWrapper(IHttpContextProvider httpContextProvider)
    {
        this.httpContextProvider = httpContextProvider;
    }

    public string CurrentRoute 
    {
        get
        {
            var context = this.httpContextProvider.CurrentContext;
            return informationFromContext;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless the consumers of this provider are containing state, instead of just logic.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this works for me since I setup a bunch of stuff in my wrapper based on the context. So then I would have to do that setup everytime it's used which I want to avoid.

Comment: In that case the comment from @Steven applies and you are [injecting runtime data into your components](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) which is the base of your current problem

Comment: @Ric.Net Ok thanks for the heads up. I think I will do a redesign. Still, haven't really got an answer to the question about performance...I know I should just try it out and measure but the refactoring required is not insignificant.

Comment: I didn't answer the question about performance as you didn't supply information about a actual performance problem. Simple injector is blazingly fast, so besides the design problem you probably don't have a performance at all

Comment: @Ric.Net Ok, thanks! I will accept this as the answer in combination with the comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to stick with constructor injection because it clearly shows the dependency. It's true that there could be a small performance hit because you have to use per-web-request, and that will involve more garbage collection than if you pass the context as a parameter. But, has it yet become a problem?

If you find this is a performance problem, you could look at a third option providing your tenant count is not enormous. You could instantiate and re-use a pool of singleton classes, where one is configured per tenant.

I've built a multi-tenant site and have certain services that need to be created for every web request, and definitely haven't had performance problems in that area.

Comment: I added an edit that this is mostly a question of optimization, I don't have a specific performance problem.

Comment: Sure, I understood that. Which is why I suggested doing what is most natural in the code, rather than optimising where you don't have a problem.

Comment: Yeah I would prefer the contructor injection, but I was more looking for an answer to the difference in performance.